# How to use toString() to convert an Array to String format for dynamically selected values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my React application, I have a filter component. Everytime I apply filters, I am calling an api by passing the selected filter values from Front End. Filter component has checkboxes so when I am selecting multiple values, it is being passed as an array of strings currently. I want to send the selected filter values as string instead of Array of Strings. I have total 2 filters- Date, Name. In my Parent component, the filters param in handleFilterChange will have all two values i.e Name as Array of Strings and Date as String which I am sending in request payload as part of filterCondition object. I want to change Name alone to String.

```
ParentComponent.js-

const ParentComponent = props => {
  const [filterObj, setFilterObj] = useState({});

  const handleFilterChange = filters => {
    console.log(filters); // Show the filter values-Date(String), Name(Array of Strings)
    const reqParams ={
      id,
      filterCondition: filters // An object with Name(Array) and date(string)
    }
    setFilterObj(filterObj);
    //API call which will pass filters in request params
    fetchApi(reqParams);
  };

  return (
    <ChildComponent onChange={handleFilterChange} />
  );
}
```

fetchApi will always send name and Date in filterCondition object. My code is working fine, the only change I want to do now is to change Array to String for name.Currently, with the above code my request structure looks like this-

Current Request Structure-

```
{
 id:1, 
 filterCondition: {
  name: ['XYZ', 'ABC'],
  date: '2020-06-29T00:00:00'
 }
}
```

I want my request to be like below-
Expected request structure-

```
{
 id:1, 
 filterCondition: {
  name: 'XYZ, ABC',
  date: '2020-06-29T00:00:00'
 }
}
```

Can someone help me understand how can I achieve the above expected request structure.

Comment: So do something like `filterCondition.name = filterCondition.name[0]`, if you only need it for a single name value. (For multiple values in there, this question doesn’t make much sense to begin with right now.)

Comment: Actually, It has nothing to do with index. My code is able to handle the selected values (including multiple selected values  )properly. I am  trying to figure out a way to  use toString() to name field so that it sends string value. Name can have multiple values, Currently it is Array of Strings, I would want to change it to only String values.

Comment: Well then use `toString` instead, if that actually gives you the format you need for multiple values - you didn’t actually specify that, so impossible for us to tell. `filterCondition.name = filterCondition.name.toString()`

Comment: My filterCondition will have all filter values. I am not able to use toString directly inside my requestParams object.

Comment: The toString() function in Javascript is used with a number and converts the number to a string. It is used to return a string representing the specified number object.

Answer (score 0):

To convert `Array` to `String` you can use `join(separator)` function

```js
var obj = {
 id:1, 
 filterCondition: {
  name: ['XYZ', 'ABC'].join(','),
  date: '2020-06-29T00:00:00'
 }
}

console.log(obj);
```